# How to replace single quotes from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['"3"', '"45"','"12"','"6"']
```

This list has single and double quotes and the item value. How can I replace either the single or double quotes from each item. I tried below, but the results are same:

```
my_list = [i.replace("''", " ") for i in my_list]
```

Comment: Your input list doesn't have single quotes in the values. Those are part of the string representations, not the contained characters.

Comment: `.replace('"',"'")` (note, the first argument is " ' ", targeting ', the second argument is ' " ', targeting the ", its a nice trick)

Comment: The *double* quote characters *are* part of the values, so `.replace('"', ' ')` would work (note that `"` is a single character).

Comment: However, this does lead me to ask: how did you get the values in `my_list` in the first place? Are you manually parsing some JSON data perhaps? There are probably better ways to do so, and to avoid getting into this situation in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep deleting your questions. As a moderator I can see that you also posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327902/how-to-compare-list-items-in-python, so you have CSV data (columns separated by tabs). Use the `csv` module to read that file and you won't have to deal with the quotes at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am reading a file which has strings and they are separated by tabs. After reading the file, I split it using tab and then store as a list and thus I guess it has both single and double quotes. Is this correct way of doing.?

Comment: You do not have single quotes. The list shows strings with the `repr()` format, the `'` single quotes are not part of the value. The `"` double quotes *are*. Use `csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter='\t')` and that quoting will automatically removed, and splitting is taken care of for you. You'll get rows with `['3', '45','12','6']`, still strings. The quotes in the list representation tell you that you have strings, and not integers; then you'd have `[3, 45, 12, 6]` instead.

Comment: See the [`csv` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for further details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list doesn't contain any strings with single quotes. I think you are confusing the `repr()` representation of the strings with their values.

When you print a Python standard library container such as a list (or a tuple, set, dictionary, etc.) then the *contents* of such a container are shown their `repr()` representation output; this is great when debugging because it makes it clear what type of objects you have. For strings, the representation uses valid Python string literal syntax; you can copy the output and paste it into another Python script or the interactive interpreter and you'll get the exact same value.

For example, `s` here is a string that contains some text, some quote characters, and a newline character. When I *print* the string, the newline character causes an extra blank line to be printed, but when I use `repr()`, you get the string value in Python syntax form, where the single quotes are part of the *syntax*, not the value. Note that the newline character also is shown with the `\n` syntax, exactly the same as when I created the `s` string in the first place:

```
>>> s = 'They heard him say "Hello world!".\n'
>>> print(s)
They heard him say "Hello world!".

>>> print(repr(s))
'They heard him say "Hello world!".\n'
>>> s
'They heard him say "Hello world!".\n'
```

And when I echoed the `s` value at the end, the interactive interpreter also shows me the value using the `repr()` output.

So in your list, your strings do not have the `'` characters as part of the value. They are part of the string syntax. You only need to replace the `"` characters, they *are* part of the value, because they are inside the outermost `'...'` string literal syntax. You could use `str.replace('"', '')` to remove them:

```
[value.replace('"', '') for value in my_list]
```

or, you could use the [`str.strip()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to only remove quotes that are at the start or end of the value:

```
[value.strip('"') for value in my_list]
```

Both work just fine for your sample list:

```
>>> my_list = ['"3"', '"45"','"12"','"6"']
>>> [value.replace('"', '') for value in my_list]
['3', '45', '12', '6']
>>> [value.strip('"') for value in my_list]
['3', '45', '12', '6']
```

Again, the `'` characters are not part of the value:

```
>>> first = my_list[0].strip('"')
>>> first         # echo, uses repr()
'3'
>>> print(first)  # printing, the actual value written out
3
>>> len(first)    # there is just a single character in the string
1
```

**However**, I have seen that you are reading your data from a tab-separated file that you hand-parse. You can avoid having to deal with the `"` quotes altogether if you instead used the [`csv.reader()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), configured to handle tabs as the delimiter. That class *automatically* will handle quoted columns:

```
import csv

with open(inputfile, 'r', newline='') as datafile:
    reader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        # row is a list with strings, *but no quotes*
        # e.g. ['3', '45', '12', '6']
```

Demo showing how `csv.reader()` handles quotes:

```
>>> import csv
>>> lines = '''\
... "3"\t"45"\t"12"\t"6"
... "42"\t"81"\t"99"\t"11"
... '''.splitlines()
>>> reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t')
>>> for row in reader:
...     print(row)
...
['3', '45', '12', '6']
['42', '81', '99', '11']
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MartijnPieters in comments, you can use replace on the strings to get the desired output.

The change I like to suggest is that using `.replace('"', '')` instead of `.replace('"', ' ')`. Otherwise the resultant strings will have a leading and trailing white space

You can use list comprehension to deal with the list you have like this

```
my_list = ['"3"', '"45"','"12"','"6"']

new_list = [x.replace('"', '') for x in my_list]

print(new_list) # ['3', '45', '12', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split:

```
[x.split('"')[1] for x in my_list]
```

or you can use:

```
[x.strip('"') for x in my_list]
```

Comment: This is hardly efficient, and won't work if the quotes are not just on the outside of the string.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean we can't give feedback on how useful the approach *is*. Not when there's `str.strip()`, for example, which is much more efficient at doing the same job.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didm't know that method. I've added to the answer.